# Marcar checkboxes quando escolher valor do select, vindo de um BD em PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, select, checkbox

Estou com um problema que não sei como resolver e não sei como procurar.
Estou construindo um sistema no `php - laravel`.
Este sistema terá níveis de usuários.

Já fiz toda a parte de cadastros, alterações, visualizações dos usuários, grupos e permissões.
Porém, travei em uma parte que provavelmente terei que usar javascript, mas tenho conhecimento muito básico em JS.

Na hora de adicionar um usuário, tenho um SELECT com os grupos (ex. ADMIN, USERS...) e uma lista de checkbox com as permissões gerais ( de todos os grupos)... até ai tranquilo, consigo selecionar o grupo e quais premissoes eu quero.

Mas precisava fazer o seguinte:
Que quando eu selecionasse (ex. ADMIN) no select, o JS já preenchesse todas as permissões que o ADMIN tem direito, e aí o usuário pudesse selecionar manualmente se deseja mais alguma permissão ou não.

Preciso fazer isso pois quando adicionar o usuário, preciso saber quais permissões são de direito de cada grupo, para assim, saber qual devo cadastrar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu recomendaria que tu fizesse uma requisição AJAX para buscar um JSON com as permissões padrões.

Por exemplo, podes criar uma rota no Laravel ('/permissoes/{grupo}') que tu pode verificar qual o grupo e retorna o JSON, naõ sei como tu salvou isso no BD, mas a princípio é só selecionar e retornar que o LAravel monta o JSON.

No teu script, quando vier o data com a resposta deste AJAX, tu percorre num forEach este JSON, para cada entrada padrão, tu busca pelo DOM usando jQuery e seta este checkbox como marcado (checked).

Um evento no select para quando o valor mudar, ele buscar as permissões padrões pela AJAX e tá feito.

Se quiser fazer mais hardcoded ainda e ignorar o AJAX, pode colocar estes JSON com as permissões de cada grupo num array no teu próprio script, vai evitar as requisições para buscar o JSON mas é uma solução menos elegante do meu ponto de vista.

Comment: Consegui resolver utilizando requisições AJAX.

Comment: Muito obrigado Evandro. Abraços

Comment: Desculpa, só vi agora aquele reply, tem mais algo que eu possa te ajudar? Ou agora está tudo funcionando como tu queria?

Comment: Sim sim, não estava muito familiarizado com php + js. Com base em seu comentário puder ir atrás e aprender mais a respeito. Vi que dá pra fazer muita coisa legal.

Comment: Que bom cara, bons estudos!

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, obrigado pela atenção Evandro.
Vamos lá...
Nunca usei Json, e como disse sei bem o básico de JS.
Mas realmente vi a lógica do que você falou, e procurei sobre esses assuntos.

Veja se estou correto:
- Devo criar um JSON com as configurações do banco: $grupo->permissões (array)(em PHP)
- Isso através de uma rota no laravel
- Chamar esse JSON na view através de AJAX
- Fazer uma função no select para 'checar' as permissões quando selecionado o grupo.
ok?

Agora surgiram outras dúvidas, se possível, conto com sua ajuda:
1ª: quando gerar esse JSON, eu preciso gerar um arquivo JSON em algum diretório?
ou existe a possibilidade de gerar uma variável JSON e jogar pra view, e conseguir acessa-la com JS?
---> vi o comando, por ex. $grupojson = $grupo->permissoes->to_json();
para transformar meu array(objeto) em JSON.

2ª Eu terei sempre que gerar esse JSON na hora de criar um usuário, ou eu crio uma vez e deixo ele armazenado pra ir acessando depois?

Após suas respostas continuamos o reto.

mais uma vez um muito obrigado pela atenção.
Não conhecia muito esse JSON, mas pelo que pesquisei, dá pra fazer muitas coisas úteis com ele, principalmente o relacionamento com outras linguagens.

Abraços